# Laravel installed, but connection is reset / No data received

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, digital-ocean, response-headers

I am using Digital Ocean as my server, I have a Ubuntu droplet running laravel fine on my site. But now I am making a 'projects backend' where there is just a folder with test projects that are all laravel projects themselves. They are not linked to the main laravel install.

I installed it, all the files are there if I go to `www.mysite.com/projects/projectname` it shows:

[image: it shows]

But when I go to the link `www.mysite,com/projects/projectname/public` it shows:

[image: firefox]

in firefox

[image: chrome]

in chrome

The site is working fine on my laptop using mamp. But not on the server?

If I look in charles (the proxy manager) I get the error / failure `Remote server closed the connection before sending response header`

I am not familiar with this, please can someone explain how to overcome this problem?

Comment: I am guessing your using apache as the web server? How did you install laravel? Did you follow here - `http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation` -- have you installed php also?

Comment: Can you show us the config of your webserver(apache/nginx)? Have you installed php? Does your laravel log contain anything?

Comment: I'm sure it's not this but I just wanna check: it's not that you use a comma accidentally in the `public` address? I.e. you definitely go to that index/listing page and then just click on `public` right?

Comment: But if this is a real issue, usually when you get connection reset it means the PHP process segfaulted while the web server was trying to execute. So you may wish to look at your PHP error log and/or web server error log (though it's likely the web server will just say that PHP segfaulted or something, and the PHP error log may not have been written to if the process crashed). But it's at least checking the logs to see if you can work out what's going on.

Comment: Have you given apache write permission to the app/storage folder and it's contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning off XCache solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing still holds for Laravel 5 and when using opcache instead of xcache. When opcache is enabled I get this error. If I put

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```

at the top of my. htaccess file, the site loads perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem, you will need to turn off XCache in your .htaccess like so:

```
php_flag xcache.cacher Off
php_flag xcache.size 0
php_flag xcache.stat Off
```

More information:
http://laravel.io/forum/08-01-2014-laravel-42-is-conflict-with-php5-xcache-module

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this problem by upgrading PHP to 5.5.22 (5.5.27 now). We had this problem with OPCache in combination with PHP 5.5.11.

Thanks to this post:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/opcache-issues

Answer (score 0):

I was having the connection reset with Laravel 4.

The problem was that I was using blade multiline comments in the views.

```
{{-- 

  line 1

  line 2 

  ....

--}}
```

When I got rid of that comments the problem of the connection reset was solved.

I'm using blade comments but single line.

```
{{-- line1 --}
```

And it's working fine.