# Laravel: Getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after file edit

Tags: php, laravel

I am setting up a Laravel application and i am not getting a response after editing files and refreshing browser. I am not running Laravel in Xampp. I also tried running my old project and it work ok.

I have tried:

- fresh installation of Composer. `composer -V` prints `1.7.3`
- fresh installation of Laravel. `laravel -v` prints `Laravel Installer 2.0.1`

After the new project is set up, i open the printed address in Chrome. The default page shows. After i edit something in view and refresh opened page, it loads for a long time and then prints out an error `CONNECTION_RESET`. My problem is similar to this one: [Laravel installed, but connection is reset / No data received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599103/laravel-installed-but-connection-is-reset-no-data-received), with an exception that i dont use Apache. Other artisan commands (make:module, make:controller) are working ok.

However, running `php -S localhost:80 -t public` instead of `php artisan serve` work ok. But i want `php artisan serve` to work. Am i missing something here?

EDIT: if i restart `artisan serve` command, the lage loads, however after first edit it does not.

EDIT2: I edited view files - html:

I changed this:

```
<div>Hello world</div>
```

To this:

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Comment: Please show the code that is executed when you edit something.

Comment: [Does this comment in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29496449/1206267) pertain to you? If so, give it a try.

Comment: @MatejJ That's fine, but it's a php module. run `phpinfo()` cntrl+f `xcache`. Does it exist?

Comment: If an error occurs **after you edit something** don't you think it could be caused by what you edited? I mean it would be a huge coincidence if it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solutions is pretty simple actually - Avast is blocking the connection; All you have to do is to add an exception for `server.php`