# Laravel gives ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after any edit

Tags: php, laravel

am setting up a Laravel starter app and i am not getting a response after editing files and refreshing browser. I am not running Laravel in Xampp, but on dev server

I have tried:

- fresh installation of Composer. Version (`composer -V`) prints `1.7.3`
- fresh installation of Laravel. Version (`laravel -v`) prints `Laravel Installer 2.0.1`

After the new project is set up, i open the printed address in Chrome. At first, default page shows ok. After i edit something in controller and refresh opened page, it loads for about 2 miutes time and then prints out an error `CONNECTION_RESET`. My problem is similar to this one: [Laravel installed, but connection is reset / No data received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599103/laravel-installed-but-connection-is-reset-no-data-received). Other artisan commands (make:module, make:controller) are working ok.

However, running `php -S localhost:80 -t public` instead of `php artisan serve` work ok. But i want `php artisan serve` to work. Am i missing something here?

If i restart `artisan serve` command, the page loads, however after first edit it does not.

EDIT2: I edited some comments in controller files:

I changed this:

```
// Make display
```

To this:

```
/**
* This function display basic info
*
*/
```

Comment: Is there anything in the php log?

Comment: No, nothing....